# How to enable Animate.css in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, animate.css

I've followed some instructions to enqueue [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) from this CDN: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/animate.css/. I referenced the second option: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css in my functions.php wordpress file.

It appears that the reference is appearing in my  when I load a page on my site, but when I add an Animate.css class to an image or a div, it doesn't animate the element, as expected.

Here's the code I've added to my functions.php file:

```
function enqueue_my_custom_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'animate-css', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css', false ); 
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_custom_styles' );
```

[Here's a page where I've added the "pulse" class](https://jewelbound.com/courses/simple-steps-to-success/lessons/take-time-to-think/) to the download icon/image, but it's not pulsing.

Comment: Please follow this https://nerodev.com/how-to-add-stylesheets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your `function.php` file do this:**

> `/**  * Load Animate CSS from MaxCDN - the right way  *  */`

```
function load_animate_css() {
  // Load Animate CSS
  wp_enqueue_style( 'animate-css', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css' );
  
  // Load Css
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_animate_css' );
```

For animation to work add **animated** class to the **pulse** class. If you want animation to loop, also add **infinite** class.

So the img tag should have classes as follows:

```
<img src="" class="pulse infinite animated"/>
```

Comment: I tried to remove all of my code in functions.php and replace it with yours but it still didn't work. I wonder what else I might be missing?

Comment: I think you have missed few classes becasue animate.css is loading

Comment: You were correct that I was loading my CSS incorrectly with the code I provided in my OP. Adding the classes "animated" and "infinite" was exactly what I needed! Thank you so so so much!

Comment: One followup question... I love that the animation infinitely loops but I'm using the CDN and am wondering if there is a way, with inline styling, to delay the animation by a specified duration. e.g. ➞ I want the animation to repeat every 6 seconds.

Comment: I asked the question over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53544967/how-to-add-delay-between-repeating-infinite-animation-via-css-override/53545036#53545036 and a gentleman gave a link to an article that outlines what I'm trying to do, but I'm not sure how to implement it in the simplest way. Do you have any idea how I could easily implement that?

Comment: I have answered the question there please check

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the link tag

```
"`<link rel="stylesheet" id="animate-css" href="https://jewelbound.com/wp-content/themes/course-builderhttps://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css" type="text/css" media="all">`"
```

**/themes/course-builderhttps://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/**

Comment: Interesting! So what do I need to change (and where) to fix that?

Comment: You should avoid such kid of answers. You should provide full answer with the proposed fix to the issue.

Comment: Pardon me, but I am a Designer cum HTML/CSS Developer, The Questioner did not mentioned that he knew the issue, as there is every chance He might have missed it. I just wanted to contribute what I could as I do not know any Scripting or programming Language except HTML/CSS/LESS.

Comment: Split the href references as right now it seems as Two swords in one sheath. '<link href="https://jewelbound.com/wp-content/themes/course-builder" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> ' and  '<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> '.

Comment: or if you have a customstylesheet you could import animate.css there. it will still work

Comment: Questioner does not need answer, but a solution. To be able to use the Animate.css stylesheet. His link tag is invalid as it contains two HTTPS addresses in one HREF reference. so removing it and Importing the same stylesheet in custom styles will definitely work. as it is a wordpress site. and custom css interface is available in wordpress.

Comment: I really appreciate you trying to help @vssadineni! You were onto something in your responses. What you discovered was a symptom of my improper enqueuing of the Animate.css stylesheet. @sahil, in the other answer has helped fix the root of the issue with his proper enqueuing code. Thanks again for digging into this for me!

Comment: Thank you, and I do not have any problem with @Sahil's answer as it is apt. But I didn't understand the reason behind inserting the stylesheet from serverside, where as you could do the same import in the custom stylesheet or in style.css was my real concern as I thought you are using bigger tool for smaller requirement.